# Returning to Main fragment when pressing back button from second activity keeps data the same fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How can I get back to the main fragment when I click the back button in activity whilst keeping the entered data in the same fragment? In the code below, I'm calling this from my second activity.

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if(fromString.equalsIgnoreCase("second")){
            //finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(fromString.equalsIgnoreCase("first")){

            finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)

        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

To go back to the fragment from my first activity I am calling `finish()` and it is working fine and keeps the data. I want this to work the same as going back to the fragment from the second activity.

Comment: I don't understand very well what you want to do but if you just want to close the fragment use fragmentManger.popBackStack()

Comment: i have a fragment , which is in MainActivity. first i enter some data in my fragment and go to second activity directly. when i press back button from my second activity , i need to finish my activity and keeps my data shown on my fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Before moving to next activity you can store the data in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) in your fragment class

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if(fromString.equalsIgnoreCase("second")){
            //finish();
            preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("pause", false);
            editor.apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(fromString.equalsIgnoreCase("first")){

            finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)

        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and in onCreate() method you can retrieve the values like

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
    boolean pause = preferences.getBoolean("pause", false);
}
```

Comment: can i retrive the values in onCreate() of main activity or in fragment ?